# Different results using ANOSIM and SIMPER in R

Tags: r, statistics, vegan

I have run ANOSIM and SIMPER to analyse community similarity at two treatments.

When I run ANOSIM the output is:

ANOSIM statistic R: -0.04465 
      Significance: 0.749

meaning they are similar to each other?

but the I run SIMPER it says the composition at two treatments are 62% different to each other?

not sure how to interpret the outputs of the two tests... why are they saying different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the documentation.

1. Are they similar to each other? Yes:

> The divisor is chosen so that R will be in the interval -1 … +1, value
>   0 indicating completely random grouping.

2. Does 62% mean the groups are different from each other? No, greater than 70% is required.

   The function displays most important species for each pair of groups. These species contribute at least to 70 % of the differences between groups.
3. There is also this note:

> The results of simper can be very difficult to interpret. The method
>   very badly confounds the mean between group differences and within
>   group variation, and seems to single out variable species instead of
>   distinctive species (Warton et al. 2012). Even if you make groups that
>   are copies of each other, the method will single out species with high
>   contribution, but these are not contributions to non-existing
>   between-group differences but to within-group variation in species
>   abundance.